# VL53L0X failing in duration test when sensing end-of-range for a while

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I'm using a single VL53L0X on the Raspberry Pi 3 in a python2.7.
Normally (in the physical set-up) it measures in this loop an infinitive(end of detecting range) distance.
When a physical object appears in the line of sight of the VL53L0X, the main software loop detects a (correct) distance change and triggers another process.

During some duration tests, I noticed that when its running this loop for a few hours and only detecting end-of-range it; it might come into a situation that an object appearing in the line of sight is not detected anymore. (the VL53L0X keeps detecting end-of-range).
This is also the case with the provided [VL53L0X_example.py](https://github.com/johnbryanmoore/VL53L0X_rasp_python/blob/master/python/VL53L0X_example.py)

Attempts so far:
1. Replacing the VL53L0X and/or Raspberry Pi does not have any effect.
2. A (sheduled) re-init by performing tof.stop_ranging() followed by tof.start_ranging.(VL53L0X.VL53L0X_BETTER_ACCURACY_MODE) does not help. A software reboot of the complete Raspberry Pi does not help either.
3. Only a complete mains power-plug down and up seems to work.

My question:
Is there a way in Python to prevent this situation or a Python command to force the VL53L0X to re-initialize or power down and up?

Comment: Update: I've resolved the issue by powering the VL53L0X by a GPIO output. In case the described situation occurs  I simply switch off&on  the sensor with the GPIO and re-initialise.